# Can't get my mic to work

Tags: audio

For some reason i cannot turn on my mic on my PC with Manjaro & KDE.
[image]

[image]

Probably, long time ago i've turned off my mic by some way i can't remember right now.
Will provide any additional system info in the comments.

Comment: Did you check your BIOS settings? Maybe you disabled the mic there.

Comment: Is it possible to disable a USB mic in BIOS?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are using a USB mic. I _think_ you can enable / disable USB ports in the BIOS but not particular USB devices.